# Implementing Template system in my joomla component

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, themes, components

I want to implement a template system for my component so that instead of view->tmpl->default.php it should redirect to a template file component->theme->sometemplate

This would help my users to make their own template for my component and add it through Joomla Backend.

Please guide me how to achieve this task.

Comment: Take a look at the current master in github. The new template manager makes it very easy to create a template override for any component.

Comment: Thanks elin.. this link solved my problem http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla .